# Printing from Visual Studio

Tags: printing, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio

How do you skip the info about where the file are on every page when you print from within Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the File-Page Setup menu item uncheck the "Page header" checkbox in the bottom left corder (VS2008).